# Strange Chart Behavior in C#

Tags: c#, charts

I have the following code. At first, the condition is true and the x axis is displayed correctly. Then I changed the condition to false but the chart could not display the x axis correctly. There is a ugly vertical line stating 1/1/1900.

If I start with the condition being false, the chart will be displayed nicely.

Thanks in advance

```
if (this.setToolStripMenuItem.Text == "Equity Curve Close to Close OFF")
  {
    chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(k.Item1, sum);
  }
else
  {
    chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x, sum);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear the point before begin of each operation? Like:  if (chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Count > 0) chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear(); or try to consider clear the series Like: if (chart1.Series.Count > 0)
                chart1.Series.Clear();

Comment: OK, so you've told a story about some stuff that happened to you. What's the question?

Comment: The question is how do I solve it?